# What are the pros and cons of docker data volumes

Tags: docker

I am looking at Managing Data in Containers. There are two ways to manage data in Docker.

- Data Volumes, and
- Data Volume Containers

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

My question is: What are the pros and cons of these two methods?

Answer (score 2):

There are basically three ways you can manage data within a container and it would perhaps be best to outline and provide some case-by-case examples as to when and why you would use these.

First, you have the option to use the [Union File System](http://docs.docker.com/terms/layer/#ufs-def). Each container that runs has an associated writable layer provided by the UFS, so if I run a container based on my choice image, the writes I perform during that session when the container runs can be committed back to the image and persisted, through the means that they are permanently associated with the image's build. So if you have a Debian image and do `apt-get update && apt-get install -y python`, you have the possibility to commit that back to the image, share it with others and save everyone the time required to perform all those multiple network requests to have an up-to-date container with Python pre-installed.

Secondly, you can use volumes. When the container runs, writes to the directories that are targeted as volumes are kept distinctively of the UFS and remain associated with the container. As long as the associated container exists, so does the volume. Say you had a container who's entry point is a process that produces logs at `/var/logs/myapp`. Without volumes, the data written by the process could inadvertently be committed back to the image, needlessly adding to it's size. Conversely, as long as the container exists, should the process crash and bring down the container, you can access the logs and inspect what happened. By it's very nature, data stored in volumes associated with such containers is meant to be transient--discard the container and the data generated by the process is gone. If the container's image is updated and your dealt a new one, or you have no need for the generated logs anymore, you can simply remove and recreate the container and effectively flush the generated logs from disk.

While this seems great, what happens with, say, data that's written by a database? Surely, it's not something you'd keep as a part of the UFS, but you can't simply have it flushed if you update the DB image or switch over from `foo/postgresql` to `bar/postgresql` and end up with a new container in each case. Clearly, it's unacceptable and that's where the third option comes in, to have a persistent, named container with associated volumes and utilizing the full scope of volume capabilities, such as being able to share them with other containers, even when the associated container isn't actually running. With this pattern, you can have a `dbdata` container, with `/var/lib/postgresql/data` configured as a volume. You can then reliably have transient database containers and remove and re-create them leniently without losing important data.

So, to recap some facts about volumes:

- Volumes are associated with containers
- Writing to volume directories writes directly to the volume itself, bypassing the UFS
- This makes it possible to share volumes independently across several containers
- Volumes are destroyed when the last associated container is removed
- If you don't want to lose important data stored in volumes when removing transient containers, associate the volume with a permanent, named container and share it with the non-persisting containers to retain the data

Then, as a general rule of thumb:

- Data which you want to become a permanent feature for every container environment should be written to UFS and committed to the image
- Data which is generated through by the container's managed process should be written to a volume
- Data written to a volume which you don't want to accidentally lose if you remove a container should be associated with a named container which you intend to keep, and then shared with other transient containers which can be safely removed afterwards

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't think of them as different methods.

Volumes are the mechanism to bypass the Union File System, thereby allowing data to be easily shared with other containers and the host. Data-containers simply wrap a volume (or volumes) to provide a handy name which you can use in `--volumes-from` statements to share data between containers. You can't have data-containers without data volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Data containers offer:

1. A sensible layer of abstraction for your storage. The files that make up your volume are stored and managed for you by Docker.
2. Data containers are very handy to share using the special "--volumes--from" directive.
3. The data is automatically cleaned up by deleting the data container.
4. Project's like [Flocker](https://clusterhq.com/) demonstrate how eventually the storage associated with a container will be shared between docker hosts.
5. Can use the "docker cp" command to pull files out of the container onto the host.

Data volume mappings offer:

1. Simpler to understand
2. Explicit and direct control over where the data is stored.
3. I have experienced file ownership and permission issues. For example Docker processes running as root within a container create files owned by root on the file-system. (Yes, I understand that data volumes store their data the same way, but using the "docker cp" command pulls out the files owned by me :-))

In conclusion I think it really boils down to how much control you wish to exert over the underlying storage. Personally I like the abstraction and indirection provided by Docker, for the same reason I like port mapping.

Comment: Thanks. But I disagree with "3. The data is automatically cleaned up by deleting the data container.". What I read from the blog is that 'removing container will NOT remove the volume', which means the data will persist, I think. Unless you do 'docker rm -v my_container' to remove the volume while removing the container.

Comment: @HyL You know I never tested it :-)  Don't forget there is a difference between "killing" and "removing" a container. Two different commands.

Comment: My understanding is that 'removing' is more serious than 'killing' a container.

Comment: @HyL It's a clean-up action. You can restart a killed VM, removing it well.... removes it :-)  I periodically purge all the dead containers and images from my development host. They accumulate over time.

Comment: @HyL Just read the docs. I never noticed the "-v" option on the docker "rm" command before. Useful to know, explains why space was not being reclaimed on my host as I expected... Thx! I have updated a related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188932/how-do-i-clean-up-my-docker-host-machine/23206588#23206588

Comment: ok, here is a clearer explanation on data container about data persistence: "Even though containers do not persist data across invocations, volumes declared by containers do. Even when not explicitly mapped to any host directory. And since docker volumes, and the data they contain, survive as long as any container references them, even indirectly, as long as the data container exists (even if not running), the data is logically and effectively “stored” within docker."

Comment: Regarding point 2 in Data Volume mappings, you also have this with data containers.

Comment: And regarding point 3, data-containers have a significant advantage as they can set up owners and permissions correctly. (Normally you use the same image for a data-container and the container which uses the data)

Comment: @AdrianMouat Can you explain more about setting up owners and permissions correctly using data container instead of data volume? Thanks

Comment: @Hy L - images such as mysql and postgres will set a user and permissions on directories. Running the container will set these up correctly, but if you bind mount to a given host directory you will need to ensure the permissions are right yourself. But please don't think of data volumes and data containers as competing methods.